# Line plot of the autocorrelation function $r_k$ at lag $k$

Tags: r, lag, autocorrelation

I am asked to construct a line plot of the sample autocorrelation function $r_k$ versus the lag $k$. I used the following **R** function

```
acf(UK.df, lag.max = length(UK.df)/4, correlation = TRUE, pl = T, xlim = c(0, 50), xlab = "Lag K", ylab = "Autocorrelation (r_k)", main = "Line Plot of Autocorrelation versus Lag for the UK Data")
```

to obtain the following plot:

[image]

However, this isn't the line plot shown in the textbook which is:

[image]

Is there a different type of line plot **R** can produce?

Comment: What does the plot you want to create look like? Is it not an ACF plot?

Comment: Please see the picture added.

Comment: They're both ACF plots, but it looks like you want a line graph. You can get the values of the ACF using the argument `acf(..., plot = F)`. You can then plot these values your self using the `plot` function with `type = "l"` for a line graph.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thanks!